# What else, if anything, needs to be clarified in the final dimensions (mm)-to-nominal-lumber-size question?

Tags: discussion

To me this question was very clear from the start, but I think too many people read the original title too literally and neglected to read and understand the first sentence of the body.

[Given final dimensions in mm, how do I choose what dimensional lumber (in customary units) to buy?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/q/1939/49)

Most of the comments suggest that people voted to close because they thought the author was asking for three numbers to be converted from mm to inches.

The question hung on without any more close votes for a long time after I pointed out the question was asking how to determine an appropriate nominal lumber size based on the desired final dimensions.

Finally, this morning drs attempted to clarify the title, but when the question rose to the top of the front page, it managed to get another close vote.

After a couple more edits from Matt and another by me, I'd like to know if anyone still thinks it is possible to interpret the question as a simple unit conversion.

Comment: I think that is about as good as your likely to get.  If someone reads your answer before voting to close, I think it might make them pause and reread the question.

Answer (score 1):

I saw the OPs intention the same way you did. The question was about matching lumber measurements between metric and imperial while using a *specific* example. The answer you gave was the ideal response I expected which help support my interpretation of the question as well.

These types of things are going to happen. The question was poorly worded and many of us clearly wanted to edit the question. Much like me I think we wanted to give the OP a chance to have some input. As of now the OP still has not been back to the site (5 days since posting).

I suppose it is possible the OP only cared about the one measurement  but in the end we (the community) did the right thing. Often, we need to look past the wording and look for other interpretations and give people the benefit of the doubt.

I just hope now some might see it in them to retract their down votes.